# Perl and XML::Smart : How to check a node's existence based on its value?

Tags: xml, perl

What perl function in the XML::Smart library ( or XML::LibXML ) allows to check if a node exists before adding it?

Example:

```
<food>
<fruit>banana</fruit>
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>orange</fruit>
</food>
```

I want to add the fruit "banana" only if it doesn't already exist.
Thanks.

Comment: What is `$j`? How does the `$data` structure look like?

Comment: $j is the "j"th element named "control". This extract is actually in a for loop to go through all the elements named "control". It reads data from another file and that part works fine.

Comment: Please, provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: <SpecificResult>
<hostname>ServerA</hostname>
<control>
        <title>ControlX</title>
        <state>1</state>
</control>
</SpecificResult>

Comment: This is the structure of the data file and it can have several elements "control" or "state". The sample code itself is too long to be posted here. My question is simply how to check a node's existence before adding it in perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about `XML::Smart` but in `XML::LibXML` you want 'findnodes'.

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML -> new() -> parse_string( do { local $/; <DATA> } );

if ( my $node =  $xml -> findnodes ( '//fruit[string()="banana"]') ) {
   print $node;
}
else {
    #insert new element
    my $new = XML::LibXML::Element->new("fruit");
    $new -> addChild (XML::LibXML::Text->new("banana"));
    $xml -> documentElement -> addChild ( $new );
}


__DATA__
<food>
<fruit>banana</fruit>
<fruit>apple</fruit>
<fruit>orange</fruit>
</food>
```

Edit: You mention in the  comments that 'grep' can be used. I'd urge you not to, for this reason - your XML as above can be (entirely legitimately, as part of the XML spec) reformatted as:

```
<food>
  <fruit>banana</fruit>
  <fruit>apple</fruit>
  <fruit>orange</fruit>
</food>

<food
><fruit
>banana</fruit><fruit
>apple</fruit><fruit
>orange</fruit></food>

<food><fruit>banana</fruit><fruit>apple</fruit><fruit>orange</fruit></food>
```

All of which are semantically identical. There's a bunch of other things - like ordering of tags and attributes - that can also cause significant grief with regular expressions. Far better to use a parser that understand the context of your XML.

Comment: I found an alternative by using shell commands in the perl script with a cat/grep "banana" on the file , but this works too. Thanks!

Comment: I would urge you not to use it - grep is inappropriate for parsing XML, because you can have multi-line XML.

Comment: You are probably right. The thing is I can't call the method "findnodes" on my $xml variable because it was created with XML::Smart and not XML::LibXML. In fact when I do " $xml -> findnodes ..." it says it can't find the method findnodes in the XML::Smart library.

Comment: To not change aaall my code to XML::LibXML, what I do is I put the output of the grep in a variable and check if it's empty or not. If it's not empty it means the word "banana" is in it, doesn't matter how the xml is formatted. Is that right?